# Multicollinearity in multiple regression that is done multiple times

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I hope that my question is understandable:

Lets start what my situation is and afterwards what exactly my question is.
I am doing a multiple regression in R and I try to predict an effects of taxes on marketing.
Therefore I got statistics from companies and I try to identify what the impact of tax rising has on marketing spending. I used different variables (if necessary I can tell them) and then did the regression. To get a better prediction/regression I had to separate the companies into their segment (200+) because not every company needs necessarily the same amount of marketing. Also I separated the data into years (20) so that the taxes influence can be better looked at. Afterwards I run the vif test on the regression to look for multicollinearity. Because of the separations I did many regressions and therefore I have about 1000 groups of multicollinearity.

What brings us to my question:
Now a few have of them (right now 8 but I will add more variables in the regression so the number will rise) have a value over 10 in vif. That means that normally (as I now is a standard process; correct my if I'm wrong (with studies to it preferred <3)) I have to delete those variables, but each variable is higher than 10 at least once.
What would mean that I had to do a completely new setup of the regression. But in the regression itself they have a p-value of below 0.00000000022.
So what should I do?
Is it fine if I leave them in because more than 90% are around 1 for the vif value?

PS: I would really appreciate if you have studies on that for me so that I can relate to them why I did so and so <3.

Comment: " Because of the separations **I did many regressions** and therefore I have about 1000 groups of multicollinearity." It's usually best to put everything together into a single regression model, e.g. including market segments and years as predictors (with appropriate handling of years with time-series methods). There's no need to delete multicollinear predictors anyway; they just lead to inflated coefficient error estimates.

Comment: I See what you are saying but as I said I have  to do so because also the guy that made me do the regression said its necessary. I also don't understand why some get the result of multicollinearity and some not. Shouldn't it be that every test group (for me its the year for each segment) gets the same result? And on top if I use years and segment as variables I get way more multicollinearity and also collinearity :/ (years could be handelt by time-series maybe (don't now how to do that) and segment is necessary to exclude the groups that have to low amount of data + other reason I already told

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e for the help on the perfect structure/spelling of my question :)